# Passing List<NavMeshBuildSource> to NavMeshBuilder.CollectSources() but it is complaining about it being void

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i am trying to build a NavMesh at runtime since the level is procedural. And when calling NavMeshBuilder.CollectSources() it complains about the last argument being of type void.

the error is : Assets\Scripts\NavMeshRuntimeBuilder.cs(24,49): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshBuildSource'

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;
public class NavMeshRuntimeBuilder : MonoBehaviour
{
    LayerMask _layerMask;

    private void SetUpNavMesh()
    {
        NavMeshBuildSettings navMeshBuildSettings = new NavMeshBuildSettings();
        navMeshBuildSettings.agentHeight = 2f;
        navMeshBuildSettings.agentRadius = 1f;
        navMeshBuildSettings.agentSlope = 2f;

        Bounds collectionBounds = new Bounds(Vector3.zero, new Vector3(99999, 9999, 9999));
        NavMeshCollectGeometry navMeshCollectGeometry = NavMeshCollectGeometry.PhysicsColliders;
        NavMeshBuildMarkup navMeshBuildMarkup = new NavMeshBuildMarkup();
        navMeshBuildMarkup.root = null;
        navMeshBuildMarkup.area = 0;
        navMeshBuildMarkup.overrideArea = false;
        List<NavMeshBuildMarkup> navMeshBuildMarkups = new List<NavMeshBuildMarkup>();
        List<NavMeshBuildSource> navMeshBuildSources = new List<NavMeshBuildSource>();
        NavMeshBuildSource navMeshBuildSource = NavMeshBuilder.CollectSources(collectionBounds, _layerMask, navMeshCollectGeometry, 0, navMeshBuildMarkups, navMeshBuildSources);

    }
}
```

[Closer look at the method with the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzbiH.png)

Comment: Please add the code to your question. Do not post code as images, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I figured it was complaining about the return type of `NavMeshBuilder.CollectSources()` was not the last argument passed to it.

I should have read error location (29,**49**) more carefully.